# Azure Data Factory - Copy data from MySQL ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][MySQL] (17) Error during communication with the server

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have issue with copy data from MySql to Azure Data Lake.
When we tried to connect to DB and select manually no issue.

but when put it in Azure Data Factory and run pipeline Copy data this error occured

> Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=UserErrorUnclassifiedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Odbc
> Operation
> Failed.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=The
> connection has been
> disabled.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
> [08S01] [Microsoft][MySQL] (17) Error during communication with the
> server.,Source=MySQLODBC_sb64.dll,'

this is detail data process from Azure
[image]

Any info what is the main caused?

Answer (score 0):

```
Error Message= Failure happened on 'Source' side.
Error Message= The connection has been disabled.
Error Message= Error during communication with the server.
```

**System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException**

The exception that is generated when a warning or error is returned by an ODBC data source.

You are getting the above errors because of a missing connection with the data source.

Make sure MySQL database is accessible to Azure services.